# What's the right way to create a XAML Border with repeating elements in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to create a border with a blue background and repeating circles. As an example:

[image]

For the vertical portion, I'm using a vertical StackPanel in a Grid. A circle (overlapping a blue Rectangle) is declared in a ControlTemplate. To produce the repetition, I've copy-pasted a bunch of ContentControls, each of which points to my ControlTemplate.

For example:

```
<StackPanel
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="3"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Orientation="Vertical"
    >
    <ContentControl
        attachedProperties:LightEllipseAttachedProperties.LightState="{Binding ElementName=PhoneApplicationPage, Path=GameController.Instance.Lights}"
        Template="{StaticResource LightbulbTemplate}"
        />

    **Repeat N times**

    <ContentControl
        attachedProperties:LightEllipseAttachedProperties.LightState="{Binding ElementName=PhoneApplicationPage, Path=GameController.Instance.Lights}"
        Template="{StaticResource LightbulbTemplate}"
        />
</StackPanel>


<ControlTemplate
    x:Key="LightbulbTemplate"
    >
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Rectangle
            Fill="#3300CC"
            Height="15"
            Width="15"
            />
        <Ellipse
            x:Name="LightEllipse"
            Height="8"
            Width="8"
            >
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush />
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My question: Is there a better way to create a border of repeating elements using Silverlight? Perhaps Border has a Tiling capability so it will repeat the ControlTemplate itself, rather than me adding individual ContentControls?

Comment: Why not use `ListBox`?

Comment: Can you just create an image that looks correct and use that instead? Creating lots of controls will make your application slower more than likely and add unnecessary overhead. And, unless it's perfectly sized, the dots won't necessarily line up nicely at all corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a simple method for building a shape like that, you could try using a `Rectangle` with a custom `StrokeDashArray`:

[image: Example]
It was generated by this XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Height="200">
    <Rectangle StrokeThickness="14" StrokeDashCap="Round" Stroke="#FF00B2E6" />
    <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="0.1 1.3" 
            StrokeThickness="10" StrokeDashCap="Round" Margin=".9"  >
        <Rectangle.Stroke>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#BFFF0606"/>
        </Rectangle.Stroke>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

The XAML uses 2 rectangles. One as the "background" color and the other for the circles. By experimenting with the `StrokeDashArray` values, you can control the shape of the dash and the distance to the next dash. By using a `Round` dash cap, and a small dash size (`.1`), it generates a shape that looks nearly round. You can experiment with the location of the `Rectangle`s, `Margin`s etc., to control the final look.

The nice part about using this technique is that it's extremely an efficient operation on the Phone to draw the shape and it will automatically resize to content as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I've a slightly different proposal (not only in XAML):

Make Background your Border. I've managed to do something like this:

[image: border]

It works quite good and automatically fits to UIElement size, thought may need some time (not much) to load (but can be prepared when you start your App and then reused). I've done it via WritableBitmap - just rendered that many elements (the adventage is that any elements may be used - stars, tringles, even other images) that I need:

```
private WriteableBitmap CreateBorderBrush(int width, int height)
{
   Rectangle firstBrush = new Rectangle();
   firstBrush.Width = 15;
   firstBrush.Height = 15;
   firstBrush.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
   Ellipse secondBrush = new Ellipse();
   secondBrush.Width = 8;
   secondBrush.Height = 8;
   secondBrush.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
   int dimensionX = width - width % 15;
   int dimensionY = height - height % 15;
   WriteableBitmap bitmapToBrush = new WriteableBitmap(dimensionX, dimensionY);
   for (int i = 0; i < width / 15; i++)
   {
       bitmapToBrush.Render(firstBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = i * 15, Y = 0 });
       bitmapToBrush.Render(secondBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = i * 15 + 3, Y = 3 });
   }
   for (int i = 1; i < height / 15 - 1; i++)
   {
       bitmapToBrush.Render(firstBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = 0, Y = i * 15 });
       bitmapToBrush.Render(secondBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = 3, Y = i * 15 + 3 });
       bitmapToBrush.Render(firstBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = dimensionX - 15, Y = i * 15 });
       bitmapToBrush.Render(secondBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = dimensionX - 15 + 3, Y = i * 15 + 3 });
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < width / 15; i++)
   {
       bitmapToBrush.Render(firstBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = i * 15, Y = dimensionY - 15 });
       bitmapToBrush.Render(secondBrush, new TranslateTransform() { X = i * 15 + 3, Y = dimensionY - 15 + 3 });
   }
   bitmapToBrush.Invalidate();
   return bitmapToBrush;
}
```

In MainPage constructor I've used it like this:

```
this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    myGrid.Background = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = CreateBorderBrush((int)myGrid.ActualWidth, (int)myGrid.ActualHeight) };
};
```

And the XAML code:

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" Height="200">
     <Button x:Name="first" Content="Button" Width="150" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a separate `UserControl`. The number of circles can be a `Dependencyproperty` of the `UserControl`. You can then use a `ItemsControl` to repeat the circles.